# Simplifying before integrating with form $(1/x)(dx/dt)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let’s say that we want to integrate
$1/(30{,}000-9x)\cdot dx/dt$

Do we have to first factor out a ($1/3$) in the denominator?

I am trying to solve an ordinary differential equation and it appears that the decision to factor or not to factor affects the final result. For instance, if you do factor, you get $+10{,}000$ on the right side eventually (that is, added to some exponential terms). But if you don’t factor, you get $+30{,}000$ on the right side eventually. Note: This is even after totally isolating $x,$ taking into account division.

Is it possible to have two totally different general solutions or is not factoring mathematically illegal for some reason?

Thanks much.

Comment: You should get the same answer. Please use Mathjax to format your equations, and show how you get two different outcomes

Comment: As best I can guess, you are mistaking different integration constants for different solutions.

Comment: \begin{align*}\int \frac{1}{30\,000 - 9x} \,\mathrm{d}x &= \frac{-1}{9} \ln|30\,000 - 9x| + C \\ &= \frac{-1}{9} \left( \ln|10\,000 - 3x| + \ln 3\right) + C \\ &= \frac{-1}{9} \left( \ln|10\,000 - 3x|\right) + \frac{-\ln 3}{9} + C \\ &= \frac{-1}{9} \ln|10\,000 - 3x| + C\text{.}\end{align*}

Comment: @BrianMoehring You might be right. Thanks so much.